# leading edge for VStack in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vstack

I want to create a *VStack* of many *Text*s with 20 points of spacing between each Text. I want my *VStack* to be aligned to left side of the screen(or leading side of parent *View*).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(){
            //alignment options: .center , .leading , .trailing
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20){
                Text("Salam")
                Text("chetori")
                Text("Arsalan")
                Text("?")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

and if you want your **VStack** to be on right side of your screen, put the **Spacer** above the **VStack**

Comment: salam,khubam mersi =) 
this aligment: .leading is just inside VStack and still show this texts on center of the view ,i want padding this whole VStack to the left of the view

Answer (score 0):

```swift
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20){
    ForEach(0..<20) { i in
        HStack {
            Text("\(i)")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading) // needed only if your text has multiple lines
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}.padding()
```

And the result:

[image]